# Can I connect an iPad to a monitor with with an Apple Digital AV Adapter converted to DVI?

Tags: ipad, hdmi, video-adapter, dvi

I need to connect my 3rd-generation iPad to an older monitor. I already own an [Apple Digital AV Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD098ZM/A). Other than the need to purchase an [HDMI to DVI cable](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10231&cs_id=1023104&p_id=2404&seq=1&format=2) is there anything preventing me from hooking my iPad up this way?

Comment: I don't see why not. Given the dearth of answers, though, it might be best for you to try it out and answer your own question.

Comment: @CajunLuke thats my line of thinking as well. Off to mono price to order the cable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and ordered an [HDMI to DVI adapter cable from Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001TH7T2U). Using this cable and the most recent [Apple Digital AV Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD098ZM/A) I was able to mirror my iPad on my old monitor.